# Faltan las cadenas "X wiki description" y "X tag wiki excerpt" en Transifex

Tags: bug, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Preguntado en Meta SE: [The Transifex strings “X wiki description” y “X tag wiki excerpt” are not being used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317938/209901)

---

Estaba revisando unas sugerencias de edición y me dirigí al [perfil del usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/103954/javier-enciso?tab=activity) que lo proponía. En ella, vi:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, aparece:

> ntlk **wiki description**

y

> ntlk **tag wiki excerpt**

Es decir, en lugar de *descripción de wiki de comunidad* (o similar) y *extracto de etiqueta* aparece el texto en inglés. Busqué en traducir.win y no encontré nada que apunte a esta cadena, ni [buscando *excerpt*](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=excerpt) ni [buscando *description*](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=description).

¿Podríais pues añadir estas cadenas en Transifex?

Comment: Una esta.. y traducidas!!! ::facepal:: keys: a01f1a122fc46a6dba3c317ad91266a2.. asi que... mmm...

Comment: seguramente no se estén usando las versiones traducidas acá... es la parte del código donde se parsea el texto en inglés usando regex y se reemplazan las variables a manopla.

Comment: @g3rv4 entonces, ¿abro pregunta en Meta.SE para que lo miren? ¿Debo hacer algo? Gracias

Comment: @fedorqui si, es el mejor camino... ahora que me cambié de equipo, no tengo una versión de SO corriendo en mi entorno (sólo de SOEnterprise) así que hacer un PR se me complica más.

Comment: Preguntado en https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317938/209901

Comment: @fedorqui si te hacen el mismo caso que me hicieron a mi con el enlace a la licencia.... :)

Comment: @Pikoh ayer paseé por Barcelona con Nicolas, a ver si eso ejerce de `sudo` y nos hacen más caso :D

Comment: @fedorqui bien,la verdad es que si de Nicolas depende se que no hay problemas, se preocupa mucho de nosotros. Pero me temo que no dependa de el.. ;)

Comment: @Pikoh absolutamente de acuerdo